# selecting from parallel arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, parallel-processing, selection

I have many (=1000+), large (=1000000+ records) data files with time, x, y, z data.

I used numpy.loadtxt against a sample file, to populate four parallel arrays; e.g.,

```
ts, xs, ys, zs = numpy.loadtxt( 'sampledatafile.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
```

I want to select a subset of these parallel arrays, where the time is in a specified range; e.g.,

```
min_time = t0  # some time, in the same format as values in the data file
max_time = t1  # a later time
```

I have been able to do this, by iterating through the ts array; like this,

```
my_ts = []
my_xs = []
my_ys = []
my_zs = []

for row in range( len( ts ) ):
    if ( min_time <= ts[row] ) and ( ts[row] <= max_time ):
        my_ts.append( ts[row] )
        my_xs.append( ss[row] )
        my_ys.append( ys[row] )
        my_zs.append( zs[row] )
```

Is there a more efficient way here?  I figure another approach is to load each record, using a csv file reader, and checking each record as it goes by, instead of numpy.loadtxt.

By surely there is a more clever way, in Python?  Something like, "select all records in the ts array meeting the criteria, and the associated elements in the parallel arrays"?  Is there is clever, and cool syntax, for this; especially if it is more efficient than the approach(es) above?

Comment: If you're using Python <3, you want to use xrange instead of range.

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = numpy.loadtxt( 'sampledatafile.csv', delimiter=',')
ts = arr[:, 0]
idx = (ts >= min_time) & (ts <= max_time)
my_ts, my_xs, my_ys, my_zs = arr[idx].T
```

---

If you would like to sort your array according to `ts` first, you could also use `np.argsort`:

```
idx = np.argsort(ts)
arr = arr[idx]
```

Comment: This only works if `ts` is the same as the output of the `range` function.

Comment: @nmichaels: He is already using `for row in range(...)` and `ts[row]`. So `ts` *can* be indexed this way -- assuming `min_time` and `max_time` are ints.

Comment: Right, I missed that.

Comment: Timestamps aren't integers, sadly.  But a clever notion, using slicing.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user2808134: Since the timestamps are not ints, you could use `np.ceil` and `int` to round them to the correct integer index. I've edited my post to show what I mean.

Comment: (Actually, I think that the use of the "len" function creates sliceable ints.  Took a while to stumble onto that.)

Comment: Yes, your code works, but when you already have a NumPy array, using NumPy slicing will be much much faster than using a `for-loop` with `append` (which creates a Python list instead of a NumPy array).

Comment: This replicates the OP's code in a much more efficient implementation, so +1, but I have trouble believing that his code works as he expects. It seems that the "right" way of doing this would be to not depend on knowing which rows contain the limiting values, but do something like `idx = (ts >= t0) & (ts <= t1); ts = ts[idx]; xs = xs[idx]; ...` Or if the times are known to be sorted, finding the rows with e.g. a couple of calls to `np.searchsorted` before doing the slicing.

Comment: Sadly, the times are neither sorted nor integers.  The loop in my code effectively does this last suggestion: idx = (ts >= t0) & (ts <= t1) in a loop, inefficiently.  Using this suggestion (creating  an idx array specifying the "happy rows" in the data,) seems to get where I need to be, using Python to efficiency.

Comment: Eek! Your times are not sorted? Then the code you posted is **not** behaving as you desire. `( min_time <= row ) and ( row <= max_time )` is testing if the **index** is between `min_time` and `max_time`. It is not testing if `ts[row]` is between `min_time` and `max_time`.

Comment: I'd agree, but doesn't the use of "len" in "range( len( ts ) )" get me around the problem of unsorted data? AND, You Are Right.  I miss-copied my original code (Sorry, my BAD); the check was actually ( min_time <= ts[row] ) and ( ts[row] <= max_time ) !  My Horrible Bad.

Comment: @unutbu - I think your solution has got it.  However, I found two things that I had to do, to get it to work properly:

Comment: @unutbu - I think your solution has got it.  

I found that the call to numpy.loadtxt had to have unpack=False as a parameter, which I had set to True in my code, in order for the final line to work.  Might be obvious, to the numpy experts out there, but hung me up a bit.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange, since `unpack=False` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about quicker or better, but shorter:

```
from itertools import izip

arrays = [arr[min_time:max_time+1] for arr in (ts, xs, ys, zs)]

zip(*arrays)
```

That will give you a list of tuples `(t, x, y, z)`. Alternatively, you could get a list of dictionaries `dict(t=t, x=x, y=y, z=z)`. If you really want them to be in 4 separate lists, what you did but with `xrange` instead of range ought to be reasonable.

Edit: Updated to take into account unutbu's slicing and fix my misconceptions.